# python django randomy selecting user and checking condition continuously

Tags: python, django

I have view:

```
winner_index = random.randint(0, participant_count-1)
winner = player_list[winner_index]
if (date.today() - timedelta(days= 4*365/12)) > next_check.win_date.date():
    final_winner = winner
else:
    final_winner = player_list[winner_index+1]
    ### Again check if this user win_date is greater then four month if yes then again generate new user
```

Here I am generating a winner randomly. If the randomly generated user has already won and if win date is less tha 4 month I am generating a new user..

Here what if the new user has also won already and its win date is not greater than 4 month... I again want to generate next new user and check if its win date is greater than 4 month..

How can I do it continuously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code into the loop:

```
final_winner = None
while not final_winner:
    winner_index = random.randint(0, participant_count-1)
    winner = player_list[winner_index]
    if (date.today() - timedelta(days= 4*365/12)) > next_check.win_date.date():
        final_winner = winner
```

Comment: I should not write else block for date check right ??

Comment: It is correct.  If the date check will fail then the `final_winner` will still be `None` and the next iteration of the loop will start.

Answer (score 0):

```
final_winner = None
while not final_winner:
  winner = random.choice(player_list)
  if (date.today() - timedelta(days= 4*365/12)) > next_check.win_date.date():
    final_winner = winner
```